Clean architecture, render email content
I have a notifications subdomain where all emails and SMS notifications are handled / sent from the system, based on integration events from other parts of the system.
Each use case creates a notification entity in the application layer and saves it using a notification repository in infrastructure. (The saved notifications are queued and ultimately sent by a scheduled job).
A notification might look like this:
 $notification = Notification::create(
            Channel::EMAIL,
            $recipients,
            $subject
            $content
            $context
        );

The email content will in many cases be more than just plain text, and this is where my question arises. The email content is a presentation concern, and should reside in the UI/presentation layer? How would the use case / application layer get this, without breaking the flow of control?
-- Update:
Since my initial posting I been reading some related literature and think I have made some progress.
First of all, some additional information on how the notifications are used:
Obviously, they are initially sent to the recipients (for example the customer in case of an order confirmation, a “manual” message sent by an employee, order cancellation email and so on). This might be email or SMS.
In the administration interface, the employees/admins should be able to see the notification history for a specific entity (for example an order), who it was sent to,, when, and status (queued, sent, error). In other words, the notifications should be persisted “indefinitely “.
For the initial presentational issue, I have introduced a presenter interface for each kind of notification. The interfaces are placed in the application layer (or should they be in the domain), and the actual implementation is done in the UI layer. As an example, an order confirmation has an OrderConfirmationPresenterInterface with a “present” method.
This is currently being used in the creation of the notification entity, the implementation of the interface as injected by DI:
$notification = Notification::create(
            Channel::EMAIL,
            $recipients,
            $subject
            $this->emailPresenter->present($orderId, $something, $somethingElse),
            $context
        );

In other words, the actual generated presentation (typically HTML for the email content) is returned by the presenter and added to the notification entity (as a string), and consequently persisted in the notification record in the database.
So for the actual presentational issue, I think I am on the right path (?). The application layer does not have any knowledge of the actual presentation of the email, it just forwards the required data specified by the presenter interface, and is given a string in return.
(Then comes the question, should I persist the actual generated presentation when creating the notification entity, or should I persist only the input data and generate the presentation when the notification is shipped.
The first alternative will ensure that the actual representation of the notification is persisted, but this means that all HTML is duplicated/persisted per record.
The second alternative will only save the data, but if the presentation logic is changed at a later point in time, a new render of the notification (when inspecting the notification log), will not necessarily look the same as the notification that initially was sent to the customer.)

I’ll phrase my answer based on the understanding I have in your current design, that is:

you divided your system in different bounded contexts
one of these bounded contexts is one in which you handle notifications (via email or SMS)
notifications are generated in other bounded contexts but sent in the bounded context you dedicated to them

(I would call these bounded contexts rather subdomains because I suppose that you chose this design based on some convenience, and not because this is an actual subdomain emerging from the business. It’s part of the solution and not part of the problem.)
If this is the case, then it seems to me that an Email may be an entity in your domain model for the bounded context you dedicated to notifications. In this case, the text of the email resides in the domain model, because it is part of what constitutes the Email entity. You may even decide to apply some invariants in the domain model based on how such a text is done or on how it changes based on some actions; invariants are to be modelled in you domain model.
For what concerns the presentation layer, instead, you may treat it as pure presentation, that is, a translator from the domain language to other languages (REST, UI…). This pattern is taken and inspired by the Hexagonal Architecture of Alistair Cockburn, and reinterpreted by the DDD community (see Khononov’s book as a reference): driver and driven ports from/to other systems are mere translators from/to the language of those systems. In your case, a presentation layer that takes an Email and transforms it into an actual email message is indeed an Adapter to an external system, hence its purpose is to translate the Email from the domain model into an encoded email message, and send it to the external system (whatever you use to send your messages).
—-
Notice, as last comment, that what you implemented is similar to the Outbox pattern: every time something meaningful happens in your domain, a new notification is stored somewhere, ready to be re-processed (in your case, sent as email message).
In some interpretations, this pattern is implemented directly in the domain instead of the application layer (see, again, Khononov for reference).
In any case a proper outbox pattern may be implemented so that every time something is put in the outbox, this is done transactionally.

Thank you for your answer. I have added a new answer with some updated information about my issue.

Thank you for your answer Eleonora. Since my initial posting I been reading some related literature and think I have made some progress.
First of all, some additional information on how the notifications are used:
Obviously, they are initially sent to the recipients (for example the customer in case of an order confirmation, a “manual” message sent by an employee, order cancellation email and so on). This might be email or SMS.
In the administration interface, the employees/admins should be able to see the notification history for a specific entity (for example an order), who it was sent to,, when, and status (queued, sent, error). In other words, the notifications should be persisted “indefinitely “.
For the initial presentational issue, I have introduced a presenter interface for each kind of notification. The interfaces are placed in the application layer (or should they be in the domain), and the actual implementation is done in the UI layer. As an example, an order confirmation has an OrderConfirmationPresenterInterface with a “present” method.
This is currently being used in the creation of the notification entity, the implementation of the interface as injected by DI:
$notification = Notification::create(
            Channel::EMAIL,
            $recipients,
            $subject
            $this->emailPresenter->present($orderId, $something, $somethingElse),
            $context
        );

In other words, the actual generated presentation (typically HTML for the email content) is returned by the presenter and added to the notification entity (as a string), and consequently persisted in the notification record in the database.
So for the actual presentational issue, I think I am on the right path (?). The application layer does not have any knowledge of the actual presentation of the email, it just forwards the required data specified by the presenter interface, and is given a string in return.
(Then comes the question, should I persist the actual generated presentation when creating the notification entity, or should I persist only the input data and generate the presentation when the notification is shipped.
The first alternative will ensure that the actual representation of the notification is persisted, but this means that all HTML is duplicated/persisted per record.
The second alternative will only save the data, but if the presentation logic is changed at a later point in time, a new render of the notification (when inspecting the notification log), will not necessarily look the same as the notification that initially was sent to the customer.)

You mentioned in a comment to another answer that you have added "a new answer" (this one), together with "some new information" about the issue. Please update your initial question with this additional information so that someone who reads the question can have a complete picture of the problem.
